# How do I swap my x and y axis on my Mendix bar chart?

Tags: bar-chart, axis, mendix

I’m using the basic bar chart widget and I’ve got it to successfully produce a chart showing percentages of people that have passed a training course on the x axis, and the name of the course as the Y axis.

[Current Bar Chart display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2yFf.png)

However I would like the bar chart to be vertical, rather than horizontal. I’ve  tried to make this change under the ‘Data Points’ section under Edit Series Item but it won’t let me select the course title as the X axis. All I see when I click on the ‘Select’ button is the following:

[Edit Series Item - Data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3AOv.png)

If I click select for my x axis I see the following:

[Chart X axis options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6IBI.png)

But if I hit ‘select’ for the Y axis I see the following:

[Chart Y axis options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhqXp.png)

My question is; why don’t I see both options when I select the x axis value and how can I fix this? I can only see the full course (abbreviated) name when it’s on the Y axis.
#frustrated

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. Use a Column chart for vertical bars like I want and a bar chart for horizontal bars.

[Vertical bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OqEm.png)